# Turtle Graphic: How can i create a ruler

Tags: python, recursion, graphics, turtle-graphics

The tallest tick mark is the one-half-inch mark,the next two tallest ticks are the quarter-inch marks and even shorter ones are used to mark the eighths and sixteenths, and soon. Write the following recursive function:  drawRuler(x, y, width, height)

```
$import turtle

'''
def height(range(4)):
  for i in

'''

Runs = 10

def drawRuler(x,y,width,height):

  if Runs == 0:

    print("End.")

  else:

    #turtle.goto(x,y)

    turtle.forward(width)

    turtle.left(90)

    turtle.forward(height)

    turtle.right(180)

    turtle.forward(height)

    turtle.left(90)

    drawRuler(0,0,width,height/4)

    drawRuler(-50,0,15,100)

    drawRuler(0,0,15,50)

    Runs == Runs - 1

    drawRuler(0,0,15,100)

$
```

my question is how do i get it to create different heights, and to create the same height later down the ruler. I feel like my function is close but still so far.

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind recursion is to use a function to break a problem into smaller and smaller chunks until the chunks can no longer be divided.

In your ruler example above you could think of it like this...

The smallest chunk would be the smallest division in the ruler.  In your case, its 1/16".
You then need to call your function, recursively, until it has divided the ruler into chunks that are 1/16". Once the length parameter in the call to drawRuler() is 1/16 of an inch the problem is simple.  You just have to draw the correct length tick mark.  You do that by deciding how to draw the tick mark by based on the length parameter in the call to your function.  If the length is 1/16 you draw a 1/16 tick mark.  If the length is 1/2 an inch you draw a 1/2 inch tick mark, etc...

Call stack would look something like this...

```
drawRuler(0, 0, 10, 1) // draw a ruler at 0,0 with a length of 10 and a width of 1
  drawRuler(0, 0, 5, 1) // draw the first half of the 10" ruler starting at 0
    drawRuler(2.5, 0, 2.5, 1) // draw the first half of the 5" ruler starting at 0
      // keep dividing the ruler until you reach the 1/16 size
      // once you reach the one sixteenth size, draw the correct size tick mark for passed in length
    drawRuler(2.5, 0, 2.5, 1) // draw the second half of the 5" ruler starting at 2.5 
      // same as above
  drawRuler(5, 0, 5, 1) // draw the second half of the 10" ruler starting at 10
    // same as above
```

The function would look something like this...

```
drawRuler(x, y, length, width)
{
   if (length > 1/16) then
      drawRuler(x, y, length / 2, width) // draw the left side
      drawRuler(x + (width * 1/2), y, length / 2, width) // draw the right side
   end if;

   // draw the tick mark here using Turtle Graphics.  The length of the tick mark 
   //   is based on the length parameter pass into the function.
   // For example,
   //   if the length is 10 or any even inch mark the length would be very long
   //   if the length is 5.5 or any 1/2 inch value the length would be long
   //   if the length is 2.25 or any 1/4 inch value the length would be medium
   //   if the length is 0.125 or any 1/8 inch value the length would be medium-short
   //   if the length is 0.0625 or any 1/16 inch value then the length would be short
}
```